# Does Google Search Console indexing the nonwww version hurt my ranking if my site is using the www version?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

Not sure if this is the right forum to post a question like this. My site at https://www.usahazmat.com is setup in Analytics using `www` and Search Console is setup with a connection to my analytics account.  I assumed when my site is indexed, it's indexed  using the `www` version of my domain.

When I use the site command [site:www.usahazmat.com](http://site:www.usahazmat.com), I only see about 1600 pages, but when I do [site:usahazmat.com](http://site:usahazmat.com) (nonwww), I see 6500 pages.

**I have two questions:**

1. Why is search console indexing the nonwww version when everything is setup for www
2. With Google indexing the nonwww version, is this hurting my ranking?  And if so, what would be the best route to fix this?

Comment: This question does not appear to be programming related you may have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This covers a few areas.

What you specify in Google Analytics his no effect on ranking. What you see in Google Analytics is based on where you place your tracking code.

What you register with Google Search Console has no effect on ranking. The way you register controls what you see. So if you register the www version, you only see data on that.

It looks like you redirect users to the www version of your site (good). Use that for everything

Did you change from none www to www. That could explain the site: search change. But you will fins better data if you look at your site in the Google Search Console.